# Has anyone been using Magepack on production?

Tags: magento2, jsbundling, advanced-bundling, baler

I've recently discovered [Magepack](https://github.com/magesuite/magepack). It's a really good tool for Magento 2 JS bundling and it gives us a much better Google Pagespeed score than Baler which I'm using.

I was able to install Magepack on a Magento default instance and I'm planning to use it for my clients, but I'm hesitant to do so as I'm not sure if it's stable to be on production yet.

Has anyone been using Magepack on production? Is that worth using it comparing to Baler?

Thanks

Comment: I am using Magepack in production with no problems, I can recommend it.

Comment: Hi Paj, Thanks for your reply. Is that ok for you to share the client site storefront URL so I can test how good Magepack is on production?

Comment: Has anyone implemented magepack on magento 2 cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself by applying Magepack to our merchants. I have applied Magepack on the following sites so far and they are happy with the speed.

1. https://medmartonline.com/ (Magento Cloud instance)
2. https://www.headcovers.com/

I recommend all Magento sites to apply Magepack to speed the frontend JS loading up.

Comment: Have you implemented magepack on magento 2 cloud?

Comment: @Toean Tam could you tell me one thing? Do you push to the repo only magepack.config.js and then on production, or you just to run `magepack generate --cms-url="production_url"` on product env?

Comment: @GieDe, Yes, I committed magepack.config.js to the repo and on the deployment pine line, I only run the magepack bundle command.

Please help to vote for the answer if that helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nkd.com/ (Commerce Cloud)

https://www.haar-shop.ch/ (OS)

https://haka.com/ (Commerce on premise)

Comment: Have you implemented magepack on magento 2 cloud?

Answer (score 0):

To install magepack on adobe(magento) cloud , follow below steps,

found .magento.app.yaml file in root folder and edit in build hooks section as,

set -e
composer install
unset NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm install --lts=erbium
npm install -g magepack
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:generate
magepack bundle
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:transfer

Answer (score 0):

hooks:
build: |
set -e
composer install
unset NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
nvm install --lts=erbium

npm install -g gulp-cli

(cd ./app/design/frontend/Fluid/blank/ &&  npm install && gulp)

npm install magepack -g
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:generate
magepack bundle
php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:transfer